# how to set global alias for a joomla component

Tags: component, url

can any body tell me how to make a global alias for a joomla! component
i want to completely get rid of joomla! components name (k2, virtuemart , etc..)

```
localhost/component/k2/item/243-3
```

i created a link to item and it's work perfectly but the items that generated by the plugins does not has alias
i will be helpfull even if i can change the component name in the url

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the alias you need to create a menu item which points to the output of your component. If there is no menu item Joomla will fall back on the component name to create an alias.